# Is it possible to go to aparticular node in a xml?

Tags: xml, parser, xmlparsing, xmlnode

I am wondering how can I search a node once I parse an XML, I need to go to the node (attached at the end of the question) "data-block" and loop through all the children to extract the value " <vs:value ", at the moment I am doing something that looks really bad as I havent figure it out how to go straight to data-block to start my loop, or even straight to the partiicular node that i need to extract the value, for example if i want to get th evalue of NA8900_xr_cur

```
public static void testing () {
    Attachment att = new Attachment();
    att = [SELECT Id, Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id='00P8s0000001czJ'];
    String s = att.Body.toString();

    DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
    DOM.XmlNode rootNode;
    DOM.XmlNode body;        
    DOM.XmlNode response;
    DOM.XmlNode product_data;
    DOM.XmlNode summary_data;
    DOM.XmlNode data_block;
    
    try{
        doc.load(s);
        rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
        // System.debug(rootNode);
    }catch(exception e){
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : rootNode.getChildElements()){
        if (node.getName() == 'body') {
            body = node;
        }
    }

    if (body == null) {
        System.debug('Body is null');
        return;
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : body.getChildElements()){
        if (node.getName() == 'response') {
            response = node;
        }
    }
    
    if (response == null) {
        System.debug('response is null');
        return;
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : response.getChildElements()){
        System.debug(node.getName());
        if (node.getName() == 'product-data') {
            product_data = node;
        }
    }
    
    if (product_data == null) {
        System.debug('product_data is null');
        return;
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : product_data.getChildElements()){
        if (node.getName() == 'summary-data') {
            summary_data = node;
        }
    }
    
    if (summary_data == null) {
        System.debug('summary_data is null');
        return;
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : summary_data.getChildElements()){
        System.debug(node.getName());
        if (node.getName() == 'data-block') {
            data_block = node;
        }
    }
    
    if (data_block == null) {
        System.debug('data_block is null');
        return;
    }
    for(Dom.XmlNode node : data_block.getChildElements()){
        System.debug(node.getName());
    }
}
```

XML Sample:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsa:MessageID
            xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">211009-CF16D-994B7
        </wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo
            xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
            <wsa:To
                xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous
            </wsa:To>
            <wsa:From
                xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                <wsa:Address>https://cteau.vedaxml.com/sys2/soap11/vedascore-apply-v2-0</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:From>
            <wsa:Action
                xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://vedaxml.com/vedascore-apply/EnquiryResponse
            </wsa:Action>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <vs:response
                xmlns:vs="http://vedaxml.com/vxml2/vedascore-apply-v2-0.xsd" response-type="report">
                <vs:product-header>
                    <vs:enquiry-id>xxxxxxxxx</vs:enquiry-id>
                    <vs:datetime-requested>2021-10-09T16:10:28.499+11:00</vs:datetime-requested>
                    <vs:datetime-generated>2021-10-09T16:10:31.872+11:00</vs:datetime-generated>
                    <vs:client-reference>xxxxxx</vs:client-reference>
                    <vs:operator-id>xxxxx</vs:operator-id>
                    <vs:operator-name>xxxxx xxxxxx</vs:operator-name>
                    <vs:product-name>VedaScore Apply®</vs:product-name>
                    <vs:permission-type code="X">CONSUMER</vs:permission-type>
                    <vs:product-data-level code="N">Negative</vs:product-data-level>
                    <vs:product-version>2.0</vs:product-version>
                </vs:product-header>
                <vs:product-data>
                    <vs:enquiry-report>
                        <vs:primary-match id-index="1" type="create">
                            <vs:bureau-reference>30YYXXXX12</vs:bureau-reference>
                            <vs:individual-name first-reported-date="2021-10-09">
                                <vs:family-name>YYYYY</vs:family-name>
                                <vs:first-given-name>ZZZZZZ</vs:first-given-name>
                            </vs:individual-name>
                            <vs:gender code="U">Unknown</vs:gender>
                            <vs:date-of-birth first-reported-date="2021-10-09" last-reported-date="2021-10-09">1980-12-01</vs:date-of-birth>
                            <vs:is-deceased>false</vs:is-deceased>
                        </vs:primary-match>
                        <vs:addresses>
                            <vs:address first-reported-date="2021-10-09" last-reported-date="2021-10-09" type="C">
                                <vs:id-references>
                                    <vs:id-reference>1</vs:id-reference>
                                </vs:id-references>
                                <vs:street-number>937</vs:street-number>
                                <vs:street-name>KENT</vs:street-name>
                                <vs:street-type>ST</vs:street-type>
                                <vs:suburb>SYDNEY</vs:suburb>
                                <vs:state>NSW</vs:state>
                                <vs:postcode>2000</vs:postcode>
                                <vs:country-code>AUS</vs:country-code>
                            </vs:address>
                        </vs:addresses>
                        <vs:consumer-credit-file>
                            <vs:credit-enquiries>
                                <vs:credit-enquiry enquiry-date="2021-10-09" type="credit-application">
                                    <vs:id-references>
                                        <vs:id-reference>1</vs:id-reference>
                                    </vs:id-references>
                                    <vs:account-type code="PF">Personal Loan (fixed term)</vs:account-type>
                                    <vs:enquiry-amount currency-code="AUD">650</vs:enquiry-amount>
                                    <vs:relationship code="1">Principal's Account (sole)</vs:relationship>
                                    <vs:credit-enquirer>
                                        <vs:name>XXXXXXXX.</vs:name>
                                        <vs:classification>SLND</vs:classification>
                                    </vs:credit-enquirer>
                                    <vs:enquiry-client-reference>0068S000000AAQD</vs:enquiry-client-reference>
                                </vs:credit-enquiry>
                            </vs:credit-enquiries>
                        </vs:consumer-credit-file>
                    </vs:enquiry-report>
                    <vs:summary-data>
                        <vs:data-block name="genesis" type="standard">
                            <vs:characteristic id="NA8900" key-characteristic="true">
                                <vs:variable-name>NA8900_xr_cur</vs:variable-name>
                                <vs:description>Number of cross references</vs:description>
                                <vs:value unit="count">0</vs:value>
                                <vs:data-level code="N">Negative</vs:data-level>
                            </vs:characteristic>
                            <vs:characteristic id="NA8904" key-characteristic="false">
                                <vs:variable-name>NA8904_age_fle</vs:variable-name>
                                <vs:description>Age of primary file</vs:description>
                                <vs:value unit="months">0.0</vs:value>
                                <vs:data-level code="N">Negative</vs:data-level>
                            </vs:characteristic>
                        </vs:data-block>
                    </vs:summary-data>
                    <vs:score-data>
                        <vs:score>
                            <vs:scorecard id="VSA_2.0_X_NR">
                                <vs:name>VedaScore Apply</vs:name>
                                <vs:version>2.0</vs:version>
                                <vs:type>Consumer</vs:type>
                                <vs:data-level code="N">Negative</vs:data-level>
                            </vs:scorecard>
                            <vs:risk-odds>9.38</vs:risk-odds>
                            <vs:key-contributing-factors>
                                <vs:contributing-factor id="KCF-001">
                                    <vs:name>Length of Credit History</vs:name>
                                    <vs:description>The time since credit activity is first recorded on file can be an indicator of risk.</vs:description>
                                    <vs:score-impactor>Moderately Increases Risk</vs:score-impactor>
                                </vs:contributing-factor>
                                <vs:contributing-factor id="KCF-004">
                                    <vs:name>Current Consumer Credit Application Information</vs:name>
                                    <vs:description>The type and amount of credit being applied for can have an impact on risk.</vs:description>
                                    <vs:score-impactor>Marginally Increases Risk</vs:score-impactor>
                                </vs:contributing-factor>
                            </vs:key-contributing-factors>
                            <vs:score-masterscale>523</vs:score-masterscale>
                        </vs:score>
                    </vs:score-data>
                </vs:product-data>
            </vs:response>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't know what your technology constraints are but the obvious answer is "XPath".

Comment: Specifically consider [apex-xpath](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/apex-xpath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SOAP call, so your obvious best bet is to get a WSDL, use the [SOAP Services](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) feature of Apex, then you can call the method like a normal method call. If your particular API call isn't supported as this way, then you'll want to use something like [XPath](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/apex-xpath) to avoid complicated parsing. However, I would strongly advise that you try importing the WSDL first, it's so much easier, as you don't have to write any explicit parsing code yourself.